How to generate thumbnail in .NET
Trying to generate thumbnails from a byte array containing jpg or png extension images and then show it on a razor page. Here is what I currently have. The byte array comes from an object class which contains a field called FileContent
Any help on what I'm doing wrong and next steps would be much appreciated
My current approach was to take the byte array of the image, resize it as a thumbnail image, and then save that as another array, finally using the byte array conversion to try and load the image on the front-end, which has not worked
Razor Page

<QuickGrid Items="@BlobNames">

        <TemplateColumn Title="Thumbnail">
        @{
            var currItem = (context as DocumentObject);
            byte[] thumbnail = GenerateThumbnail(currItem.FileContent);
            var thumbnailUrl = $"data:image/jpeg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(thumbnail)}"; 

        }
</QuickGrid>



Backend
protected byte[] GenerateThumbnail(byte[] imageStream)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageStream))
    {
        using (Image originalImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
        {
            using(Image thumbnail = originalImage.GetThumbnailImage(64,64,()=>false, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                using(MemoryStream thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    thumbnail.Save(thumbnailStream, originalImage.RawFormat);
                    return thumbnailStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When I run the program I get the following error:
Unhandled exception rendering component: The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.DrawingCom' threw an exception.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.DrawingCom' threw an exception.

Have you read the Remarks on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-8.0

you might want to rethink how you are approaching this. generally thumbnails are generated as separate image files that have much lower resolution and quality. you would typically persist those thumbnails to disk and retrieve them later when needed. recalculating thumbnails at runtime kills the whole point of thumbnails, which is performance gain. you still will save on network traffic with your current approach, but with computational cost..

Yea you are correct, I have instead decided to generate the thumbnail once, and store them in a database to retrieve later.

I was able to find a solution in using a Image Sharp for the thumbnail generation.
With the ImageSharp Library I was able to use a method called Image.Load(MemoryStream ms) which didn't generate the same error as I was getting prior

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
